# Remove WooCommerce image

Tags: image, woocommerce, product

As directed here, I inserted the following code to stop my product images from showing at full width with WooCommerce.

```
.single-product .product .summary 
{ 
   width: 100% !important; 
   float: none !important;
}
```

Since I update my theme/Woocommerce, **this code no longer works** (the product image still appears).

Please help me with code to remove the product image.

Comment: What do you mean by "showing in full screen"?

Comment: As in full width- I want to have a single page, with a long gravity form to fill out (several page form). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. In wc-template-hooks.php ("WEBSITE"/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes) I changed:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

TO

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

Also, added the following to custom.css

```
.single-product .product .summary 
{ 
   width: 100% !important; 
   float: none !important;
}
```