# Remove WooCommerce product image from Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I’m trying to remove WooCommerce product image in my WP page (I'm using eStore template). I don’t need the product image to be shown, but when I remove the product image using the following PHP snippet, I get a blank space where the image is supposed to be, and it looks terrible:

```
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_product_thumbnails’, ‘woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails’, 20 );
```

I've tried to remove the image placeholder by inserting the following CSS snippet, but nothing happens:

```css
.single-product .product .summary {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Could you please give me some guidance on this?

Note - this code come from: [Remove WooCommerce image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619633/remove-woocommerce-image)

Comment: we need to see more code so we can help you. for example the html/php code where you print the image or the url of your project (if its online)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the image gallery area display as nothing and 100% should fill the area. I tried the following with your CSS on the default template and it worked for me:

```
.single-product .product .images { display:none; }
```

And here is an example page for those wondering:

https://demo.themegrill.com/estore/product/shoe-for-men/

Koda

Comment: Excellent! It works! I added this line of code to the 'style.css' file in my child theme and it works allright. Thanks!

Comment: @RodrigoMoreno is this code disable the ability to upload images for products? No more product images when product is published?

Answer (score 0):

the image variable/object is being shown on this template you are using. if you cannot figure that out, just do a super hacky:

```
divName img {
display:none;
}
```

and move on to learning how to manipulate the templates inside WooCommerce for better flexibility. You could even write a function to hide this image...